# Postfix would not auto-create the Maildir for incoming mails

Tags: postfix, email-server, mailbox

I am trying to setup a mail server, I went over tons of tutorials on how to do this with `Postfix` + `dovecot` + `MySQL`, but none was error-proof and I always got stuck at some point with an error, so I decide to configure the mail server step by step by my own, so far I have installed `Postfix` and `ViMbAdmin` as my postfix-admin interface, I managed to link the database with Postfix, everything is fine but one! The Postfix would not auto-create the Maildir for incoming mails.

The following is a sample `mail.log` output for an incoming email:

```
postfix/smtpd[22086]: connect from mail-lf0-f45.google.com[209.85.215.45]
postfix/smtpd[22086]: C92B461E5B: client=mail-lf0-f45.google.com[209.85.215.45]
postfix/cleanup[22090]: C92B461E5B: message-id=<BLAH@mail.gmail.com>
postfix/qmgr[21732]: C92B461E5B: from=<BLAH-SENDER@gmail.com>, size=4535, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/virtual[22080]: C92B461E5B: to=<BLAH-RCVR@XXX.net>, orig_to=<BLAH-ALIAS@XXX.net>, relay=virtual, delay=0.13, delays=0.13/0/0/0, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/mail/vhosts/XXX.net/BLAH-RCVR/mail: unable to create lock file /var/mail/vhosts/XXX.net/BLAH-RCVR/mail.lock: No such file or directory)
postfix/smtpd[22086]: disconnect from mail-lf0-f45.google.com[209.85.215.45]
```

If I **manually** create the `/var/mail/vhosts/XXX.net/BLAH-RCVR/` directory, everything will go fine. I want the application auto-create the directory so I don't have to create it for every user I add to system!

What am I missing in here?

---

P.S: I've double checked the permission on `/var/mail/vhosts/` the postfix should be able to `RWX` the directory.

Comment: I know that `postfix-admin` does it but not `postfix` itself.  I don't know `ViMbAdmin` but I suppose that's where you need to focus to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know postfix-admin nor ViMbAdmin but creating a maildir is as simple as:

```
mkdir -p $USERHOME/Maildir/{new,cur,tmp}
chown -R <mail user>,<mail group> $USERHOME/Maildir
chmod -R 700 $USERHOME/Maildir
```

where $USERHOME is the mailbox home directory (virtual user home directory).

You can write a simple bash script to run every time you create a new mailbox, or you could somehow insert that script in the ViMbAdmin mailbox creation process.

Another solution is to utilize Dovecot LMTP server to deliver local mail, instead of postfix LDA (see [Dovecot LMTP documentation](http://wiki.dovecot.org/LMTP)).
It creates maildirs and has much more features (sieve scripting for example).

Regards

Paolo B.

Answer (score -1):

This is the job of the LDA (local delivery agent).

See the complete install example for Ubuntu (13.10 so slightly old): https://github.com/opensolutions/ViMbAdmin/wiki/Mail-System-Install-on-Ubuntu

If followed, this absolutely works fully :-D

And see the configuration for the LDA: https://gist.github.com/barryo/8918488#file-dovecot-15-lda-conf

Comment: Please provide the actual answer and not just links.